# How can I code "first Monday of the next month" when user input is a date?

Tags: excel, date

How can I program Excel to output `first Monday of the next month` when the input is `a date`?

Comment: Please explain. By code, do you mean VBA? Or do you want a formula?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the date is in cell A1, a formula like the following should do the trick.

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1)+(7-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1) + 1,1),12))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate version (assuming the date is in cell A1):

```
=EOMONTH(A1,0)+MATCH(2,WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(A1,0)+{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=EOMONTH(A1,0)+8-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(A1,0)-1)
```